# Crypto++ AES encryption with pbkdf2

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, crypto++

I would like to encrypt text using pbkdf2, but each time I execute my code the derivekey output is different. How can I fix the output?

The code is for making key to utf8 bytes, making sha256 hash from the utf8 bytes, and making pbkdf2 key and iv.

My code is following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "modes.h"
#include "aes.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "sha.h"
#include "base64.h"
#include "pwdbased.h"
#include "misc.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char text[] = "For test";
    size_t targetSize = sizeof(text);
    char key[] = "asdlkj32"
    size_t keySize = sizeof(key);
    
    // convert key to utf8
    string baseKey(key);
    int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_COMPOSITE, baseKey.c_str(), baseKey.length(), nullptr, 0);
    wstring utf16(size, '\0');
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_COMPOSITE, baseKey.c_str(), baseKey.length(), &utf16[0], size);
    int utf8Size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, utf16.c_str(), utf16.length(), nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    string utf8(utf8Size, '\0');
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, utf16.c_str(), utf16.length(), &utf8[0], utf8Size, nullptr, nullptr);

    // Make sha256 hash
    unsigned char shaChar[1000];
    CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;
    auto temp = (unsigned char*)utf8.c_str();
    hash.CalculateDigest(shaChar, (unsigned char*)utf8.c_str(), utf8Size);
    string sha(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(shaChar));
    sha = sha.erase(sha.find_last_not_of(-52) + 1);

    CryptoPP::byte* test = (unsigned char*)reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(sha.c_str());
    
    // Make pbkdf2 key and iv
    CryptoPP::byte derive[pbkdf2KeySize + ivSize];       /*deriveKey output buffer*/
    size_t derivesize = { sizeof(derive) };

    const CryptoPP::byte* ppkey = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(key);

    CryptoPP::PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA256> pbkdf;
    size_t temp1 = pbkdf.DeriveKey(derive, derivesize, 0, ppkey, keySize, test, sha.length(), 1000, 0.0f);        /* Each time the output of this function is different */
}
```

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: I changed the code. it may work directly in console app with crypto++ library.

Comment: please provide a [mre], the code provided doesn't compile

Comment: Print out all the variables (bytes as hexadecimals) right before calling `DeriveKey` and find out which one changes value over multiple calls.

Comment: The salt length is specified incorrectly. Replace the 7th argument `sha.length()` in `DeriveKey()` with `CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE`. With this change, the expected result for PBKDF2 is produced. Note that usually the salt must not be derived from the key (as here as SHA256 hash), but a random value should be used, to be generated with a cryptographically secure random number generator.

Comment: I solved it. I changed the code `sha = sha.erase(sha.find_last_not_of(-52) + 1);` to `sha = sha.erase(sha.find_last_not_of((char)-52, (size_t)1000) + 1);` and it works. When the sha variable is made it took more length than I expected and the variable got trash value at the end. Thanks for the advises!